# How can I tell who forked my repository on GitHub?

Tags: github, git-fork

Is there a way to know who has forked my repository on GitHub? I can see the number of forks, but I'd like to know who forked my repository and what kind of changes they made to it.

I know they can send me a pull request if they're interested in contributing back to my repository, but is there some other way for me to find out who forked my repository?

Comment: Who wants an API for it can try: `https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/forks`

Comment: For foreign repos: `Insights` -> `Forks` https://docs.github.com/en/github/visualizing-repository-data-with-graphs/listing-the-forks-of-a-repository

Comment: Small update: Non of the methods in the answers below show the full list if the amount of forks is above 1000. With the api you can see max 30 forks, with the fake pull request max 200 and with the `network/members` page max 1000 forks. So at the moment the full list is not accessible for heavily forked repo's...

Comment: As per https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#forks API can show a max. of 100 forks and supports paging just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your repository and click "Insights", then click "Forks"
Choose Period "All time"
Click the Repository type drop-down and tick the options as in the picture below.
Sort by Recently updated.

[image]

Remember though, anybody can download your repository without it being a fork.
You wouldn't have a clue what that person will do with your code.
If somebody forks your repository, it's usually a goodwill gesture by GitHub members who
want to make changes, & sometimes contribute back by making a pull request.
Other people might just want a static copy where they can be assured no changes are made.
There are in fact an endless amount of reasons why people fork repositories.
Once the code is public, there is no return.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Turns out all of the forks of my repo are inactive. Thanks.

Comment: Just as an aside, the forkers of my repo are all serial forkers, ie., they have forked 100 or more repos. So it seems just a method to keep placeholders of things.

Answer (score 190):

Clicking the number of forks shows you the full network. From there you can click "members" to see who forked the repo. Example for ExpressJS: https://github.com/expressjs/express/network/members.

[image]

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer.. can someone fork from my repo which is public and make that repo private, so that I don't know that they forked from my repo?  At https://github.com/kbsbng/Bank-Interest-Calculator/network, I see that there is one fork for my repo (in the number count at the top), but I see none other than my own repo in the list!

Comment: @kbsbng maybe it doesn't show anything there until they've actually made changes/commits

Comment: This solution is plain wrong.  For example it **fails utterly** for things like https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/network/members

Comment: @Tino can you elaborate? This is what I see at that link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/C9arQ.png (and many many more, if you scroll down)

Comment: @MattBall Your answer is helpful 99% of the time.  Nevertheless it still is wrong ;)  Look at the red box in your screenshot.  "shows you the full network" != "only some of this network's repositories".  The requester explicitly asked for "all" -> hence even "plain wrong" and "fails utterly" (sorry).  Anyway **this is not your fault** as there probably is no definitive answer to this.  I experimented with `api.github.com` but came to no useable solution due to the GitHub rate limit.

Comment: GitHub broke this feature - used to work for me, but now they changed it to instead just create a NEW fork, and they removed the option to see the forks (breaking their own design language - nice!). Fortunately @djzhao's answer below gives the 2022 workaround - you now need to go to a separate page to access the original feature.

Answer (score 40):

now you can check the forks in `Insights` -> `Forks`

Comment: This does not work, it just says "No forked repositories found" even though the fork count reads 2.

Comment: Hello @Scott Franco, Try to change the Forks filters(period or Repository type), then  you will see the results.

Comment: Turned on all 5 types, period 2 years (as long as I have been on github). No change. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 11):

One way I discovered from the browser is attempting to create a pull request and then compare across forks. All the existing forks would show up.

Comment: Great answer – in my case this showed up two users who had both been deleted from GitHub, one for DMCA violations, that didn't appear with any other route.

Comment: nice hack, i could find forks this way

Comment: This should be the correct answer.. works better than others

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer above helps to see the accounts who forked the repository. In order to meet the other requirement, i.e. *see what kind of changes have been made* you will need to go to each individual forked repository and then see the compare tab (please refer to the attached  picture).[image] To see exact details on what files have been actually changed you should click on the **compare** button shown in the image.

The above process is the right way and can be tedious. In case you want to see the summarized information of how ahead or behind is each forked repository you may use the link https://forkinfo.herokuapp.com/, which I have open sourced [here](https://github.com/abhishek9sharma/ForkInfo) in case you want to edit it as per any specific requirements. It fetches information about how much a fork is  ahead or behind the parent fork, by getting that information from homepage of each forked repository (from the part highlighted in the image). This information is generated based on comparison of [repositories](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/)