# How to view github forks made by a username

Tags: git, github

How to view github forks made by a username.
I would like to view the list of all forks made by a certain person (e.g. `http://github.com/<username>/forks`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know who forked my repo on github?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208450/how-do-i-know-who-forked-my-repo-on-github)

Comment: No, I want to know the forks made by myself (i.e <username>) and not on a certain project.

Comment: @Stony Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but i assume you want to list all the forks made by your `<username>`

For that case just go to below link

```
https://github.com/rpj?tab=repositories
```

You can see there are filter-buttons for "Forks".