# find all forks with changes of a given github project

Tags: github

I'm looking on an abandoned github project which has more than 300 forks. Most of them are identical, without any changes introduced after forking. Is there any way to filter only those where changes have been made? Alternatively, to sort by "similarity" to the original project.

Comment: To get the difference of each project you need to use comparisons https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/,  or use the link in the format https://github.com/0704681032/freecodecamp/compare. I have faced similar issues and https://forkinfo.herokuapp.com/ is an attempt (WIP) to fetch all compare links, open sourced at https://github.com/abhishek9sharma/ForkInfo. For more details refer this related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208450/how-can-i-tell-who-forked-my-repository-on-github/54585418#54585418

Comment: It's really frustrating when projects are abandoned and result in fork hell like this.  I wish GitHub handled this scenario better. https://github.community/t/what-is-github-policy-about-abandoned-repositories/117668/6  There's a browser add-on to at least hint that a fork is the de facto successor: https://github.com/musically-ut/lovely-forks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly: I would list those forks, and, for each one, use the [Event API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) to list **[push events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent)**:

Any push event more recent then the last push event on the original repo means that fork has potentially seen some changes.
You can then sort the forks by number of recent push events, to get a sense of "similarity".

Comment: sadly, this is not sufficient in practice, as many make changes and never make pull requests, or the pull requests do not get merged, even if they are good, and thus it is very common to have useful changes in forks/branches that are older then the last commit on the main repo.

Comment: @hoijui I agree, since I am experiencing the PR not merged right now ;) (https://github.com/jpillora/opts/pull/26). This is a start though.